# What distribution do the rows of the Stirling numbers of the second kind approach?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, normal-distribution, stirling-numbers

In wikipedia about the Pascal triangle:
[Relation to binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle#Relation_to_binomial_distribution_and_convolutions)

"When divided by 2n, the nth row of Pascal's triangle becomes the binomial distribution in the symmetric case where p = 1/2. By the central limit theorem, this distribution approaches the normal distribution as n increases."

> How can I find the distribution approached by the rows of the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number_of_the_second_kind)?

$$\begin{array}{llllllll}
 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 3 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 7 & 6 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 15 & 25 & 10 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 31 & 90 & 65 & 15 & 1 & \text{} & \text{} \\
 1 & 63 & 301 & 350 & 140 & 21 & 1 & \text{} \\
 1 & 127 & 966 & 1701 & 1050 & 266 & 28 & 1
\end{array}$$

After all the Stirling numbers of the second kind satisfy the recurrence:
$$\left\{{n+1\atop k}\right\} = k \left\{{ n \atop k }\right\} + \left\{{n\atop k-1}\right\}$$

Where as the Pascal triangle satisfies the recurrence:

$${n \choose k} = {n-1 \choose k-1} + {n-1 \choose k}$$

If such a distribution does exist I would like to find the x value for the maximum of the distribution for each row and see if it says anything about x/LambertW(x).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

*Stirling Behavior is Asymptotically Normal*,
L. H. Harper,
**The Annals of Mathematical Statistics**
Vol. 38, No. 2 (Apr., 1967), pp. 410-414

[Link](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-mathematical-statistics/volume-38/issue-2/Stirling-Behavior-is-Asymptotically-Normal/10.1214/aoms/1177698956.full)